# How to avoid "'_a" type without repasting

Tags: generics, ocaml, polymorphism

Sorry, I'm bad in English.

I'll start with simple example:

```
    let find2 f g x =
            let rec _find2 = function
                    | h::t -> if f h && g h then h else _find2 t
                    | [] -> raise Not_found
            in
            _find2
    ;;

    let find = find2 (fun _ -> true);;
```

`find` has type

```
    ('_a -> bool) -> '_b -> '_a list -> '_a
```

so this is not polymorphic code, as I want it to be.
I read about it and I know why it is happening, but I don't know how to solve it without duplicating code. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to avoid running into the so-called "value restriction" is to make sure that your declaration *syntactically* defines a function. In most cases, you can easily do so by making one parameter explicit, like so:

```
let find g = find2 (fun _ -> true) g
```

Comment: It really works. I thought I tried that, but I propably forgot about some other place in code. Thanks!